# Workaround for Dell's lack of drivers for macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: catalina, printing, driver

I've got two Dell printers - a C1760nw color printer and a B1165nfw Mono MFP.

Both of which are currently unusable after the upgrade to macOS 10.15 Catalina. Is anyone aware of a workaround or non-Dell drivers that I could use while Dell clings to their non-apologetic "circumstances beyond our control" refrain ...?

Answer (score 2):

The one-stop-shop for open source print drivers is here:

http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Models similar to your Dells seem to be supported.

If the printers can interpret PostScript or PDF natively, then you should be able to get by with a 'Generic' print queue. This would not necessarily have device-specific controls, but should be enough to print.